# I can't pass my props through Route render

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I face with "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" propblem. I am planning to create a Favourites component and pass same props that 'AllProducts' receives. I will show them on Favourites component accordint to their 'isSelected' prop.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

import Navigation from './components/Navigation';
import AllProducts from './components/AllProducts/AllProducts';
import Favourites from './components/Favourites'

import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navigation />
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/favourites' component={Favourites} />
        <Route path='/' ecaxt render={(props) => <AllProducts {...props} />} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My container component.

```
 import React, { useState } from 'react';

    import AllProducts from '../../components/AllProducts/AllProducts'

    const ProductBuilder = (props) => {
      const [products, setProducts] = useState([
        { id: 0, title: 'Red Scarf', content: 'A pretty red scarf.', isSelected: false },
        { id: 1, title: 'Blue T-Shirt', content: 'A pretty blue t-shirt.', isSelected: false },
        { id: 2, title: 'Green Trousers', content: 'A pair of lightly green trousers.', isSelected: false },
        { id: 3, title: 'Orange Hat', content: 'Street style! An orange hat.', isSelected: false }
      ])

      const buttonClickHandler = (id) => {
        const cloneProducts = [...products];
        const cloneElement = { ...cloneProducts[id] };
        cloneElement.isSelected = !cloneElement.isSelected;
        cloneProducts[id] = cloneElement;
        setProducts(cloneProducts)
      }

      return (
        <div>
          <AllProducts products={products} buttonClickHandler={buttonClickHandler} />
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default ProductBuilder;
```

My chlid component that doesn't receive props.

```
import React from 'react';
import Product from '../Product'

const AllProducts = (props) => {

  let product = (
    props.products.map(prd => <Product
      key={prd.id}
      title={prd.title}
      content={prd.content}
      id={prd.id}
      isSelected={prd.isSelected}
      clicked={props.buttonClickHandler}
    />)
  )

  return (
    <div>
      {product}
    </div>
  );
}

export default AllProducts;
```

My NavLinks

```
const Navigation = (props) => {
  return (
    <Nav>
      <Ul>
        <li><StyledNavLink to='/' exact  > All Products</StyledNavLink> </li>
        <li><StyledNavLink to='/favourites' > Favourites </StyledNavLink></li>
      </Ul>
    </Nav>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you have to do is check to make sure props.products is not undefined before using map.

```
const AllProducts = (props) => {
  if(!props.products) return null;
  let product = (
    props.products.map(prd => <Product
      key={prd.id}
```

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you explained is expected with respect to your code. Note that with link you, (I mean your navigation) when you click on the one that points to `All Products`  you send just the string pathname and hence accessing product is going to be null(since no props `products` are sent.),  Remember that The render prop function of route has access to all the same route props (match, location and history) which means to pass something like the products via link you either will want to do it by not just passing a string to the `to` of link but and object like so

```
<Link to ={{pathname: '/', products: "Product array here"}} > All Product </Link>
```

If that is not the case then I think you should have used `ProductBuilder` in the route. Also looking at the implementation of the ProductBuilder its works because you just directly pass the product array as props to the `AllProducts` component. [React router render method](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-render-methods)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I can't implement ProductBuilder because It is a container component. I would add the Favourites component into the ProductBuilder component. They should share same array with AllProducts. Therefore if implement ProductBuilder Favourites page will stand under the AllProducts page. I tried to send array manually to NavLink but error still stays there.

Comment: Ohh How did you try manually? I think I made a mistake in the instructions. this is how it should have been done. <Link to ={{pathname: '/',state:{ products: "Product array here"} }} > All Product </Link>

Comment: also you can get it by using `const {products} =  props.location.state`